# Travis-CI running two android emulators

Tags: android, travis-ci

I have a use case where two devices can communicate (peer-2-peer) over rest.

I'd like to test this use case on Travis-CI.  The [Travis-CI android guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android) points to an [example project](https://github.com/pestrada/android-tdd-playground/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk7
env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-19  ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - build-tools-19.0.0

before_script:
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - adb wait-for-device
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

It appears from the example that I should be able to create two AVD's.

**Question:** will the Travis CI environment support creating and starting two AVD's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

I found previous experiments:

[Build 599: Test wear experiment (6-7 minutes)](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/44013346)

[Build 600: Test two emulators simultaneously without boot-anim (6-7 minutes)](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/44015832)

[Build 601: Test two emulators simultaneously with boot-anim (10-15 minutes)](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/44016971)

**Previous response: based on build 605**

I experimented this possibility a year ago (android + wear) but I don't remember the results. This depends on the machines (use `sudo: false` and the container infrastructure, newer machines) and your script (avoid to run simultaneously heavy tasks like downloading dependencies while one of the emulators is being created).

I searched in google my experiments and found this commit:

https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/jobs/44038271
https://github.com/ardock/iosched/commit/88838ef1694b034f12b6ae4dc78615e8302689bd

> Update compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 21.
>
> Update wait_for_emulator.sh to support more than one emulator
>   simultaneously. Add ANDROID_SERIAL env variable to support multiple
>   emulators using adb/gradle. Create a second AVD with android-wear-20
>   as target by default. Start a second emulator for an android wear
>   device. Add before_script logic to switch between emulators when using
>   adb/gradle commands. Add optional ${WEAR_PKGS:-} variable to support
>   specific android-wear-21 updates. Add new build matrix job allowing
>   failures and using android-wear-21.
>
> If ANDROID_SERIAL is defined, commands runs for a speficic device. The
>   default behavior of running across all connected devices will occur if
>   ANDROID_SERIAL is not defined or is empty. An exception will be thrown
>   if the targeted DSN is not found. See
>   https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/108985/
>
> Currently we don't need a second emulator but can be useful in the
>   future. Combining ANDROID_SERIAL and project names we can select a
>   specific task for a specific project using Gradle.

I think that it's possible with restrictions. For example you'll need to delete the `adb -e` flag in the wait for emulator script like [here](https://github.com/ardock/iosched/commit/88838ef1694b034f12b6ae4dc78615e8302689bd#diff-2c2bb13c39347540bf9e07e618776bb0L6) and play with the `ANDROID_SERIAL` variable like this:

```
before_install:
  - export ANDROID_SERIAL='emulator-5554'
  - echo y | android update sdk -u -t platform-tool,tool,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository
  - echo y | android update sdk -a -u -t ${BUILD_TOOLS},${MOBI_PKGS:-},${WEAR_PKGS:-}

install:
  - echo n | android create avd -f -n "${MOBI_NAME:-mobi}" -t "${MOBI_TARGET:-android-21}" -b
      "${MOBI_ABI:-armeabi-v7a}" -g "${MOBI_TAG:-default}"
  - echo n | android create avd -f -n "${WEAR_NAME:-wear}" -t "${WEAR_TARGET:-android-20}" -b
      "${WEAR_ABI:-armeabi-v7a}" -g "${WEAR_TAG:-android-wear}"
  - emulator -avd "${MOBI_NAME:-mobi}" -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - emulator -avd "${WEAR_NAME:-wear}" -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - adb wait-for-device get-serialno
  - ./gradlew --version
  - ./gradlew clean
  - ./gradlew compileDebugSources compileDebugTestSources compileReleaseSources

before_script:
  - ./scripts/wait_for_emulator.sh
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - adb logcat *:W | tee logcat.log>/dev/null 2>&1 &
  - ANDROID_SERIAL='emulator-5556'
  - adb wait-for-device get-serialno
  - ./scripts/wait_for_emulator.sh
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - ANDROID_SERIAL=''
  - adb devices -l

script:
  - ./gradlew build connectedCheck
```